# Modeling a multi-channel communication device in C#

Tags: c#, design, architecture, api, communication

**Background**

We (my coworkers and I) are architecting a high level C# API to interact with a hardware device's native Windows DLL.

First I will discuss the hardware-architecture, then get to the software-architecture part.

*Main Device*

The device has the following components:

- Exactly 10 receive channels
- Exactly 4 transmission channels

*Receive Channels*

There can only the exact specified number of receive channels on the device per the hardware specification (no more no less). The receive channels keep their own buffers as well as various getters/setters for their internal hardware configurations.

I have decided to declare the channels as a public 10 element array inside the "main device" class, for the following reasons:

- Whenever new data is received we check the addresses on all channels in the "main device" to know which channel the received data is intended for. This is currently done in a foreach loop which is nice and clean.
- When assigning the properties of the channels I can do so easily by using a foreach loop (again, provides cleanness).
- Need to access the actual object, not just return an instance of the object.

*Transmit Channels*

I have decided to declare the channels as a public 4 element array inside the "main device" class, for the same reasons as the *receive* channels.

**Problem**

1. The channels are publicly exposed.
2. As one of my colleagues has asked, "what if someone enters an invalid index into the array?"

**Question**

Is the array the proper way of going about this? Is there another way? I am looking for some suggestions on the general architecture.

*Reminder:* I need to access the channel objects directly, however we go about it.

Comment: "Need to access the actual object, not just return an instance of the object." Why?

Comment: @KaseySpeakman I need to change the state of those objects.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why. I'm assuming you don't want to change the state of the object on the receive channel, because then that's not the actual data that was received anymore. But passing a reference to the receive channel's objects will do exactly that. Semantically, it's no longer a receive channel.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman actually you don't want to assume that. There are properties of each of my 10 receive channels that need to be configured independently. I state this in my question, in the first paragraph under (Receive Channels). "various getters/setters for internal hardware configurations".

Comment: @KaseySpeakman let me shed some more light on this...

Comment: @KaseySpeakman This is a facade pattern... 1. There can only be exactly 10 receive channels. 2. Each of the 10 receive channels has speed settings and other settings that I need to custom configure during run-time for various applications. 3. The receive channels must exist within the "Main Device" because they need access to a C++ hardware handle that's been marshalled up.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman so my question becomes... is there any other way to do this... other than making the receives and transmits public properties? Does that make sense?

Comment: A couple of tricks to prevent IndexOutOfRange are probably the very least of your worries. If you're going to offload much of the device interop minutia onto the callers of your API, then you are far more likely to get support calls on that. Instead of providing this as an API in front of the device, it would probably be better to provide a collection of helper functions/classes to ease interop and still let the caller be responsible for interfacing directly with the device. At least until the use cases for the API are more established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should keep the amount of channels abstracted:

- The amount of channels may vary in the future, e.g. hardware up/downgrade (new devices)
- You may want to reserve some channels in the future, e.g. for out-of-band communications and notifications

The exactness should be kept and ensured in initialization.

You should expose the channels with the least specific type possible, such as `IEnumerable<ReceivingChannel>` and `IEnumerable<TransmittingChannel>`.

The `MainDevice` should expose a way to initialize or manage these collections, you have several non-exclusive options:

- Constructor parameters

```cs
private List<IReceivingChannel> receivingChannels = new List<IReceivingChannel>();

private List<IReceivingChannel> transmittingChannels = new List<ITransmittingChannel>();

public MainDevice(IEnumerable<IReceivingChannel> receivingChannels,
                  IEnumerable<ITransmittingChannel> transmittingChannels)
{
    this.receivingChannels.AddRange(receivingChannels);
    this.transmittingChannels.AddRange(transmittingChannels);
}
```

- Fluid initialization methods

```cs
public MainDevice WithReceivingChannels(IEnumerable<IReceivingChannel> receivingChannels)
{
    this.receivingChannels.AddRange(receivingChannels);
    return this;
}

public MainDevice WithReceivingChannels(params IReceivingChannel[] receivingChannels)
{
    return WithReceivingChannel((IEnumerable<IReceivingChannel>)receivingChannels);
}

public MainDevice WithTransmittingChannels(IEnumerable<ITransmittingChannel> transmittingChannels)
{
    this.transmittingChannels.AddRange(transmittingChannels);
    return this;
}

public MainDevice WithTransmittingChannels(params ITransmittingChannel[] transmittingChannels)
{
    return WithTransmittingChannels((IEnumerable<ITransmittingChannel>)transmittingChannels);
}
```

Perhaps throw an exception (e.g. `InvalidOperationException`) in case you use these methods after the object has been first used by actual worker methods.  Or better yet, have these methods in a builder class, where you finally call `GetDevice` which will create and initialize the device, possibly with dependency injection (I will not discuss DI here.)

- Methods

  `AddReceivingChannel`, `RemoveReceivingChannel`, `AddTransmittingChannel`, `RemoveTransmittingChannel`

  `GetReceivingChannels` returning `IEnumerable<IReceivingChannel>`, or a similar `ReceivingChannels` property

  `GetTransmittingChannels` returning `IEnumerable<ITransmittingChannel>`, or a similar `TransmittingChannels` property

  `GetReceivingChannelById`, `GetReceivingChannelByAddress`, `GetTransmittingChannelById`, `GetTransmittingChannelByAddress`

Don't use settable properties, as that is asking for trouble.  The `MainDevice` should be the only entity responsible for managing its actual composition.

This way, you may start by using arrays or lists to store the channels, but switch to dictionaries or trees (e.g. `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`) if accessing them by some key becomes a bottleneck.  And the users of `MainDevice` are just as happy.

You can define a base interface `IChannel` for the common things that all channels do, such as opening and/or closing with an optional timeout, and have `IReceivingChannel` and `ITransmittingChannel` hold the specific operations, such as receiving and transmitting with an optional timeout:

```
public interface IChannel
{
    void Open(TimeSpan timeout);
    void Close(TimeSpan timeout);
}

// I'm using generics, but you don't have to if you'll always
// deal with the same data type, e.g. IEnumerable<byte>
//
// I'm also over-simplifying by not stating end-of-transmission
// and other usual channel state.

public interface IReceivingChannel<out T> : IChannel
{
    T Receive(TimeSpan timeout);
}

public interface ITransmittingChannel<in T> : IChannel
{
    void Transmit(T obj, TimeSpan timeout);
}
```

In case you need to access some inner object from a channel, define specific interfaces on which you may use the `as` operator instead of the actual class.  For instance, a `IFrobberContainer` interface with a `GetNativeFrobber` method (or similar `NativeFrobber` property), which does **not** extend `IReceivingChannel`.

This way, any object can contain a frobber:

```
public interface IFrobberContainer
{
    IFrobber NativeFrobber { get; }
}

internal class FrobberReceivingChannel : IReceivingChannel<Thing>, IFrobberContainer
{
    public void Open(TimeSpan timeout) { /* ... */ }

    public void Close(TimeSpan timeout) { /* ... */ }

    public Thing Receive(TimeSpan timeout) { /* ... */ }

    public IFrobber NativeFrobber { get; private set; }
}

internal class FrobberTransmittingChannel : ITransmittingChannel<Thing>, IFrobberContainer
{
    public void Open(TimeSpan timeout) { /* ... */ }

    public void Close(TimeSpan timeout) { /* ... */ }

    public void Transmit(Thing obj, TimeSpan timeout) { /* ... */ }

    public IFrobber NativeFrobber { get; private set; }
}
```

In case you have something extra to do with frobber channels, you can ask if the channel has a frobber using the `as` operator.

With the new C# 6 null-conditional operator, you can do this:

```
(channel as IFrobberContainer)?.NativeFrobber?.Frobulate();
```

instead of this:

```
var frobberContainer = channel as IFrobberContainer;
if (frobberContainer != null)
{
    var frobber = frobberContainer.NativeFrobber;
    if (frobber != null)
    {
        frobber.Frobulate();
    }
}
```

By segregating these distinct aspects into interfaces, you make your actual objects more flexible, more easily replaceable and mockable (good for unit testing).

---

If you insist on having 10 receiving channels and 4 transmitting channels, then you probably shouldn't use collections, but conversely use very good names for 14 properties.  For generic iteration, you can keep internal collections initialized once, to avoid obvious code repetition.

You should still use interfaces and document which ones each channel implements, instead of using actual classes as the types for these properties, to retain the replaceability benefits for refactoring, maintenance and testing purposes.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time in putting this together.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a hardware device, I would not worry too much about being able to dynamically add or remove channels, rather I would keep it simple stupid. As a consumer of the device interface i would better off accessing it like this,

```
var device = //initialize the device

device.In1.Write(dataIn1);
device.In2.Write(dataIn2);

var out = device.Out1.Read();
```

so the channel interface would look like follows,

```
IWriteChannel{
   bool Write(object data);
}

IReadChannel{
   object Read();
}
```

This is pretty simple interface, and if you want you can add types to the interface as well. For example

```
IWriteChannel{
   bool Write<T>(T data);
}
```